# Primefaces 5 overlayPanel broken after update

Tags: jsf, primefaces, overlay, panel

Today I discovered a new bug in P5. When I update the button which the overlay panel is referring to, it doesn't work anymore - The overlaypanel is not shown anymore.

As a workaround I do use `PF('widgetVar').loadContents();` but this feels very uncomfortable.

In PF4 this did work without any workarounds.

Anyone got some solution?

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

- don't update single button that opens overlay, update both
- also add `dismissable="false" showCloseIcon="true"`
- in the case you are using overlay on a dialog: add `appendTo="@(body)"`

Example code:

```
<p:commandButton value="updateSection" update=":form:overlayPanelGroup" />
<h:panelGroup id="overlayPanelGroup">
  <p:commandButton id="openOverlayBtn" process="@this" value="openOverlay"/>                                
  <p:overlayPanel for="openOverlayBtn" showEffect="fade" hideEffect="fade" dismissable="false" showCloseIcon="true" appendTo="@(body)">
    <h:outputText value="textSample"/>
  </p:overlayPanel>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you are pointing at. What do you mean with updating the button?

For me the following code works fine with PrimeFaces 5.0:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pm="http://primefaces.org/mobile">
<h:head>
</h:head>
<h:body>
    <p:commandButton id="menuButton" value="Menu" icon="ui-icon-home"/>

    <p:overlayPanel for="menuButton" widgetVar="menuPanel" at="left" showEffect="push">
        <!-- overlayPanel content goes here -->
    </p:overlayPanel>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Does this help you with your problem?

Comment: sorry if my question is unclear. In your example add a new button with update:menuButton and click this first. Then the overlayPanel is not shown

Comment: You mean that you are updating the Button, which is responsible for showing the overlayPanel, by another Button before? Is that right?

Comment: exactly. I figured out that it does work when I put the button for the overlay panel and the overlaypanel in a <p:panel> and trigger an update on that, but in previous primefaces versions this worked without an additional panel..