# why blur event is triggered when textarea is displayed via overlay primefaces

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Hi I´m using primefaces 5.1 and jsf 2.2

I´m facing this problem, When I show a textArea who is contained by a overlay, the textarea blur event is triggered, later when i click out the blur event is triggered again, like is supposed to.

this is my for each who displays all the overlay components

```
<p:panel id="results" widgetVar="wresults">
<h:graphicImage id="docImage" styleClass="imageDocument"
                    value="file/#{documentController.file.nameFileRepository}?#{documentController.getCoordenades()}"
                    style="width: 100%; ">
</h:graphicImage>

<c:forEach items="#{documentController.file.anotationList}" var="a">

    <p:panel id="anotation_#{a.id}" widgetVar="anotation_#{a.id}"   
         style="background: transparent; border:none; padding: 0px; width: 4%; height:2%; top:#{a.top}px; left:#{a.left}px; position: absolute;">
        <p:graphicImage id="img_#{a.id}" name="images/anotation.png"    style="width: 100%; height:100%;" />
    </p:panel>


    <p:overlayPanel id="imagePanel_#{a.id}" for="img_#{a.id}"  hideEffect="fade" appendToBody="true">
        <p:inputTextarea id="tarea_#{a.id}" rows="5" cols="30" value="#{a.text}">
            <p:ajax event="blur" oncomplete="modifyJS('anotation_#{a.id}')" process="@this" />
        </p:inputTextarea>
    </p:overlayPanel>

    <p:draggable for="anotation_#{a.id}" opacity="0.3" containment="parent" />
</c:forEach>
</p:panel>
```

this is how looks in the screen after click in one of the `<p:graphicImage>`

[image]

when I load or resize page I have two  Java Scipt listeners who get the window size and paint all the "blue eyes" `<p:panel id="anotation_#{a.id}" >`

these are the listeners

```
$(window).resize(function() {
clearTimeout(id);

setTimeout(function() {
    paint()
}, 300);

});

$(document).ready(function() {
setTimeout(function() {
    paint()
}, 300);
});
```

this is the function paint

```
function paint() {

var x = window.innerWidth;
var y = Number($('.imageDocument').css("height").replace(/[^0-9\.]+/g, ""));
paintAnotations([{name : 'sizeX',value : x}, {name : 'sizeY',value : y  } ]);
}
```

I`m thinking that the problem is in the paintAnotations method, paintAnotations is a remote comand who calls the managed bean and the method in the managed bean updates``

the remote comand

```
<p:remoteCommand name="paintAnotations" actionListener="{#documentController.paintAnotations}"></p:remoteCommand>
```

The method in the managed bean

```
public void paintAnotations() {

   //Set new size for the items

    RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
    context.update("form:results");
}
```

Finally this is the method who catch the blur event

```
function modifyJS(idHtml) {

console.log("blur event");
//other stuff

}
```

this gif shows the behavior

[image]

PD: if I change the textarea value, I can´t get the new value using jquery or the managed bean is like if never changes.

**What I tryed:**

*Changing the overlay event by showEvent="mouseover", but the blur is called even more times.

*Don´t refresh the screen after repintar method (in the managed bean), that works but when I resize the elements doesn´t change the size of them , and this is imperative.

*Delete the overlay panel this works, but I need to show the textarea using the overlay panel

Thanks  a looot  in advance for your time and answers

Comment: Could be due to your copy/paste, but you're lacking a left bracket in `<p:remoteCommand name="paintAnotations" actionListener="#documentController.paintAnotations}"></p:remoteCommand>`

Comment: Hi @Thrax yes, is a copy paste mistake, thanks. now i´ve edited the question

Comment: After many hours attemting to fix the problem I found this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23695239/primefaces-5-overlaypanel-broken-after-update  based on that I switched from version 5.1 to 4 and this works, so is a primefaces bug. I don´t think in this like a answer for the question. @BalusC how I should mark this question?